# controller cant access the id of panel in view

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to convert asp.net project into MVC.although it runs fine on simple asp.net but on MVC im getting an error.
Here, is a simple View with a panel that shows all products.

```
asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelProducts" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Here, is its controller,

```
ProjectModel pm = new ProjectModel();
            List<Product> products = pm.getAllProducts();

            foreach (Product product in products)
            {

                Panel productPanel = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblPrice = new Label();

                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + product.image;
                imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
                imageButton.PostBackUrl = "Product.aspx?id=" + product.Id;

                lblName.Text = product.Name;
                lblName.CssClass = "productName";

                lblPrice.Text = "$" + product.Price;
                lblPrice.CssClass = "productPrice";

                productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

                PanelProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);

                return View();
```

The error im having is that the controller cant access the id= panelproducts in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view (i.e. _ProductList.cshtml) and from your controller do "return PartialView("_ProductList", products).

In your _ProductList.cshtml, use Razor syntax such as the code below. Webforms is different than MVC. The point of MVC is separation of UI/View from your Controller. You can't continue programming like in WebForms where you directly access the UI controls from your controller as that defeats the purpose of MVC.

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
<div id="PanelProducts">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <a href="~/images/Product.aspx?id=@product.Id" class="productImage">
            <img src="~/images/@product.image" />
        </a>
        <br />
        <label class="productName">@product.Name</label>
        <br />
        <label class="productPrice">@product.Price.ToString("C2")</label>
    }
</div>
```